# My program in visual studio isn't showing anything, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out a math problem for my sister. So as a little project for myself I'm trying to write a program to solve the problem. The goal is to find out what age you would be when you become a millionaire. It looks good, but it isn't producing anything. I can't even get cout to print anything to the screen. What's wrong with it? I'm using c++.

```cpp
int _tmain()
{
    int age = 21, year = 1;
    double salary, salaryIncrease, amountSaved, interestEarned, 
        total, totalMed;
    salary = 38500, salaryIncrease = .10, 
        interestEarned = .045, amountSaved = .25, total = 0;    
    while (total < 1000000){
        if (year % 3 == 0){
            salary = salary * salaryIncrease + salary;
        }
        if (year = 10) interestEarned = .0525;
        totalMed = salary * amountSaved;
        total = (total + totalMed)*interestEarned;
        age++;
        year++;
    }
    cout << "Age = " << age << endl;
    cout << "Total = " << total << endl;
    cout << "hello?" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line while you can see the values of all variables and how they change their values, then it would be *very* easy to spot such mistakes. In fact, every time you get some unexpected behavior, then your first reaction should be to step through the code in a debugger. A debugger is just as an important tool as the compiler.

Comment: `total = (total + totalMed)*interestEarned`:  new concept in compounding?     Usually, if I have some `total` money now, and there is some `interest` which is a fraction between 0 and 1, what I want is this: `total += total * interest`. Or, if you will: `total = total * (1 + interest)`.   Based on your `if (year = 10) ...` line, erroneous as its condition may be, I can surmise that your `interestEarned` variable is between 0 and 1.

Comment: always good to turn on max warning level /W4

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( year = 10 )
```

needs to be

```
if( year == 10 )
```

Comment: Consider writing such constructions as `if( 10 == year )` - for cases of mistype (e.g. `if( 10 = year )`) compiler will find an error (l-value must be variable) and you will see the problem

Answer (score 1):

`year = 10)` is an assignment, what you should do is a comparison `year == 10`.

Change `if (year = 10)` to `if (year == 10)`.

You should initiialize your variables like this:

```
double salary = 38500, salaryIncrease = .10, amountSaved = .25, interestEarned = .045, 
total = .0, totalMed;
```

But i recommend to write it like this:

```
 double salary = 38500.0;
 double salaryIncrease = 0.10;
 double amountSaved = 0.25;
 double interestEarned = 0.045;
 double total = 0.0;
 double totalMed;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, although writing double that many times seems like a pain. I wasn't thinking I was going to show my code to anyone, so I didn't try to make it pretty. But I've heard you should always write like someone will see.

Comment: @RyanLocke it is a good practice always to write code for others to read  == or for yourself when you revisit the code in 1/2 year.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out if(year = 10) needs to be if(year == 10).

Also, I am not sure, about your logic here. 
After the first iteration -> 
total = totalMed (which is 1/4 of the sal) * 0.045

Hence, my total would be roughly 1% of sal, approx 385.

Are we trying to make this move to 1000000? In, which case we have a very long running while loop. Possibly, why you are not getting any output is something is still being processed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code, such as the `(year = 10)` condition which actually assigns to `year` and has been noted numerous times. That problem just causes the wrong interest to be used.

The main reason you don't print anything is that `total` never reaches the goal.

It doesn't reach the goal because you keep multiplying `total` by an interest figure which is in the range [0, 1), and using the result as the new total.

If we have some interest `i`, and a principal amount of money `p`, when the interest is compounded, we then have `p + ip` or `(1 + i)p` money. In C++ terms, `p = p * (1 + i)`, or `p += p * i`.   The interest earned is `p * i`, and we add that to `p`.

You're updating `total` like this:

```
 total = (total + totalMed)*interestEarned;
```

If `interestEarned` is a value like 0.0525, think about what that does to the value in `total`: `total` becomes 5.25% of the sum of its previous value plus `totalMed`.  You must re-think the financial mathematics here.

**To better understand what is going on in your program, single-step through the loop and examine the values of your variables at every step. Or put some output statements into the body of the loop which dump the values of some of the loop variables.**  At each step, ask yourself whether the variables are going in a direction which makes sense.

As is, your program doesn't produce any output until that loop is done. If the loop is never done, then there isn't any output.